# Как импортировать большой текстовый файл в БД MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Как можно импортировать большой текстовый файл (размер 51Гб) в БД MySQL? Буду пробовать на локалхосте. Как потом перенести такую большую БД на сервер?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самое простое после перегона базы на локалхосте тупо скопировать всю папку с базой и перенести архивом или любым другим способом. Но это если база в MyISAM.

Пробывал таким способом перегнать tecdoc. Mysqldump отрабатывал минут 15 а вгрузка sql длилась больше часа. Перенос базы файлами прошел за 2 минуты все что надо отключить mysql скопировать папку базы данных на сервер по samba или sftp перезапустить mysql на сервере

Для импорта можно попробывать navicat но скорее всего он не потянет.
Я в свое время для этой задачи писал мини програмку на c#. пхп такое не потянул хотя возможно если поковырятся в настройках поднять лимиты можно и им

Answer (score 1):

Вы не дали никакой информации о характере данных в этом файле, но предлоложу, что это некий файл с разделителями (CSV). Такой формат эффективнее всего грузить средствами самого SQL:
[LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html)
попробуйте локально, в случае успеха повторите то же самое на хостинге.

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql -u myuser -p < dump.sql
```

запрашивается пароль MySQL пользователя

```
Enter password:
```

Вводим пароль и ждем когда закончится импорт базы данных и опять появится приглашение коммандного интерпретатора.

**myuser** - имя вашего пользователя mysql

**dump** - дамп вашей базы данных

Если запрашивает имя БД :

```
mysql -u myuser -p MYDB < dump.sql
```

**MYDB** - имя вашей базы данных